# Wireless service not working

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-7

I have not had any problems with my PC until I switched it on this morning, the following error message comes up:

> "The windows wireless service is not
>   running on this computer, a network
>   cable is not properly plugged in or
>   may be broken"

I have scoured the net and have not been able to find a solution to this reoccurring problem. Any help would be really appreciated.

**PC info:**

Windows 7 home premium

advent Intel core 2 cpu t5600, 32 bit operating system

Comment: Please give some tips according what you have already tried? Maybe some virus check? - I recommend malwarebytes for that.

Answer (score 2):

Click on start, enter services.msc. Check if the service "WLAN Auto config" service is running. If not, start it and try again.

Comment: Hi Socken23 cheers for the advice I tried what you said and it has come up with windows could not start the wlan autoconfig service on the local computer. error 1067:the process terminated unexpectedly

Comment: Have you run any Windows updates or installed any software in the last few days?  Sounds like you've got some corrupt system files.  (You might try System Restore to the last time things worked.)

Comment: Hi Shinarai I did a system restore but alas no difference :((. No I havent installed any software, I have scoured google and this seems to be a problem that is very hard to solve